# Цикл if работает некоректно

Tags: python, if, txt

Смысл задачи: проверка наличия ника. В теории должно работать так: в открытом на чтение файле проходит перебор строк, и если существует ник, аналогичный введённому, то программа выдаёт ошибку, иначе данные пользователя вносятся в систему. На практике, данные пользователя всегда вносятся в систему, независимо от того, существует ли такой ник в системе.

```
    self.nicke = open('nicks.txt', 'r')
    for self.line in self.nicke:
       if self.nick in self.line:
          self.errnick()
          break
       elif self.nick not in self.line:
          self.nicke2 = open('nicks.txt', 'a')
          self.nicke2.write(self.nick + '\n')
          self.nicke2.close()
          self.lsdata = open('lsdata.txt', 'a')
          self.lsdata.write(self.nick + " " + self.name + " " + self.sername + " " + self.fonenumbers + " " + self.email + " " + self.sity + " " + self.date_of_birth + " " + self.password_1 + '\n')
          self.lsdata.close()

          self.regdata = open('regdata.txt', 'a')
          self.regdata.write(self.nick + self.password_1 + '\n')
          self.regdata.close()
          self.yesreg()
          break
    self.nicke.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
found = False
for self.line in self.nicke:
   if self.nick in self.line:
       found = True
       break

if found:
    self.errnick()
    break
else:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю такой вариант вообще без использования циклов

```py
#main.py
def main(nick: str = 'anton'):
    with open('./nick.txt') as file: # Условие f'\n{nick}\n' из расчёта что каждый ник хранится в своей строке
        if f'\n{nick}\n' in file.read():
            pass  # Выполняем то что нужно если ник нашёлся
        else:
            pass  # А тут если ника нет в файле

# nick.txt

anton
kirov
leb
kifirov
```

Comment: f'{nick}\n' наверное?..

Comment: @Jack_oS Если использовать f'{nick}\n' то если ник попадётся в другом нике (прим. nick='anton'  [klon, slon, gde**anton**]) будет выдавать совпадение

Answer (score 0):

- Имеем цикл с одним оператором условия, обе ветви (`if` и `elif`) которого на конце имеют `break`.
- В этом цикле мы проходимся по итератору строк файла.
- На первой итерации, на основании первой же линии файла, мы заключаем о уникальности ника во всех остальных линиях файла.

---

```
for self.line in self.nicke: # Итерация линий файла
    if self.nick in self.line: # Проверка наличия ника в любой части линии файла
        # ...
```

---

Допустим мы ищем ник `"Charlotte"`, а первая линия - `"M. Charlotte Evergreen"`. В этом случае код первого условия `if` отрабатывает. Если я вас правильно понял, правильней было бы поставить `==` за место `in`. В этом случае условие `if` было бы ложным и мы бы перешли к `elif`.

Тут можно было бы ввести логическую переменную, означающую уникальность ника в файле. После цикла можно проверить ее значение и заключить о уникальности ника.

```
IsUnique = True
for self.line in self.nicke:
   if self.nick in self.line:
      IsUnique = False
      break
if IsUnique == True:
    # ...
else:
    self.errnick()
    # ...
```

Если файл не объемен, то этот код можно свести к следующему:

```
if self.nick in self.nicke.read().splitlines():
    # ....
else:
    self.errnick()
    # ...
```